# Ember Subdirectory Models vs Adapter Change?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I noticed that it's possible to create subdirectory models with ember cli. So I can do

```
ember g model log/type1-log
```

This creates a log directory with the type1-log model inside it. The reason I attempted this was that of my API structure.

```
/api/v1/logs/
/api/v1/logs/type1-log
/api/v1/logs/type2-log
/api/v1/logs/type3-log
```

Initially, I was doing `ember g model type1-log`, but that model was doing api requests to `/api/v1/type1-log`. I wanted it to be doing `api/v1/logs/type1-log`.

Are sub directory models supported by Ember, or should I actually be updating my Adapter to modify the URL?

Requesting logs is not the only thing my api will do in the future so I do not want to set a namespace to `/api/v1/logs` in the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize end point customization using the adapter. so in your case I would say, You can create model specific adapter and use `namespace` property to customize it.

```
ember g adapter type1-log
```

and

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1/logs'
});
```

From ember guides,

> If you have one model that has exceptional rules for communicating with its backend than the others you can create a Model specific Adapter by running the command ember generate adapter adapter-name. For example, running `ember generate adapter post` will create the `app/adapters/post.js` file.

Reference:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/customizing-adapters/
https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.14/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter

Comment: This would force my API to always go to api/v1/logs which is unwated. I will clarify the question a bit more.

Comment: Adapter is responsible for providing the URL for ember-data. this is model specific adpater with namespace customization approach is correct IMHO. If you want to take control over URL generation, then you need to over write specific method from Adapter, for `urlForRequest` or any other which is suitable for you.

Comment: So I should have an adapter for each model then...? Each one having it's own custom namespace?

Comment: Yes. that's how we can customize it in ember-data. In this guide page they explained model specific adapter concept. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.14.0/models/customizing-adapters/

Comment: You can avoid having model specific adapter, and write everything in application adapter, but that's not suggested approach. this was the reason model specific adapter features implemented in ember-data

Comment: That I haven't read in ember guides or anywhere. that may be used for purely for folder structure, nothing other than I don't find any other valid use cases...

Comment: You can create dummy LogsAdapter which should inherit from `ApplicationAdapter` and create Type1LogAdapter adapter which should extend `Type1LogAdapter->LogsAdapter-> ApplicationAdapter`. In this way you can write adapter logic in specific adapter.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look into this! I was hoping to get a few more answers from other Ember gurus..

Comment: there is ember-data channel in ember slack community where you can catch core people who are working ember-data. You can get invite from https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/ ..